# Removing the email extension but want to keep the "@" but ignore the yahoo.com part. Not printing out the @ sign

Tags: javascript

//Need help printing out the xxx@ but removing the yahoo.com from the email address

```
function emailSort(){
var emails = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value.split("\n");
var users = [],  l = emails.length, id;
while (l--)
    if ((id = emails[l].match(/(\w+)\@/)) && (-1 === users.indexOf(id[1])))
      users.push(id[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var v="abcd@yahoo.com";
console.log(v.split("@")[0]+'@');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
document.getElementById('emailTextarea').value.replace(/yahoo\.com$/, '');
```

Comment: Might need a `g` flag in there

Comment: How would you extend this to handle any domain?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the `@` and take a substring up to that location:

```
email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@')+1)
```

With regexp, replace the `@` and what follows with just a `@`:

```
email.replace(/@.*/, '@')
```